# Jquery Mobile Lock Android Scaling

Tags: android, mobile, jquery-mobile, scaling

I am working on a framework for A mobile site using Jquery Mobile. Has anyone been successful at locking the ability to scale for the android phone? Right now I am using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />`. This works for all phones, but for Android I can scale. Is there anything I can do in Javascript or change the view port settings? Any guidance, demo, or links would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can use html meta tags to achieve that like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

see example at http://tab.pagesjaunes.fr

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I by using that code I can still scale the page size with the Android. I could also do it to the page you sent me.

Comment: Are you using a HTC Sense device ? Which os version... ?